# RMAN log file with date and name in Oracle 11gR2 in Linux

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle-11g-r2, linux, rman

I have a script and I want to create my log file with datetime and with unique name. It's my script:

```
.......
.......
rman target/  LOG='/u01/backup/logs/rman.log' <<EOF
.......
.......
.......
EOF
```

How can I do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were doing this in the **bash** shell on Linux, I'd use the **date** command:

```
$ date '+%y%m%d-%H%M%S'
20191115-111213

$ LOG_PATH="/u01/backup/logs"
$ UNIQUE="NAME"

$ rman target / LOG="${LOG_PATH}/rman.${UNIQUE}.$(date '+%y%m%d-%H%M%S').log" <<EOF
. . . 
EOF

$ ls ${LOG_PATH}
rman.NAME.20191115-111314.log
```

Remember that you'll need to *clean up* all these log files, from time to time.

Comment: Thank you so much.